# Helping in finding an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

What is the value of the following integral ?!

$\int\sqrt{(1+(\frac{x}{h})^{2})^{-1}-b}~~~dx$

I have tried on it as :
Let  $y=1+(\frac{x}{h})^{2}$
$dy=\frac{2x}{h^{2}}dx$  Thus  $dx=\frac{h^{2}}{2x}dy$  and  $\frac{h}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{y-1}}$
Hence the integral become  $\int\sqrt{(y)^{-1}-b} \frac{h^{2}}{2x}~~dy=\frac{h}{2}\int\sqrt{y^{-1}-b} \frac{1}{\sqrt{y-1}}=\frac{h}{2}\int\sqrt{\frac{y^{-1}-b}{y-1}}~~dy=\frac{h}{2}\int\sqrt{\frac{1-yb}{y(y-1)}}~~dy$
But i can not complete it , can you help me ??

Comment: What is the source of the problem?  If the problem is **not** from a book or class, then you can ignore the rest of this comment.  I tried to attack the problem and failed.  My experience with these types of problems is that (for me) it is not a good idea to try to *re-invent the wheel*.  I end up blundering in the dark.  There should have been previous problems, worked examples, or theorems (i.e. **tools**), that led to this problem that are on point.  The problem is supposed to be an application of the tools.  So, the natural question to ask is : what tools have you been provided with?

Comment: This integral is [an elliptic one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: @metamorphy how we can deal with it as an elliptic one ? At the end of her question she has reached to formula that not match any formulas of elliptic one ,? I am asking to learn and understand from you if it is possible

Comment: @user2661923 there are no tools it is a function on a mathematical physics book and the question ask about it is integration . The book just give me the function and ask to substitute it on the integration

Comment: @metamorphy I have solved it as following Let        $1+〖(x/h)〗^2=sin^2⁡θ$ then we get $-ih∫_∅^(π⁄2)▒〖√((1-b sin^2⁡θ ) )    dθ〗$ and thus we get the result $-ih[E(√b)-E(sin⁡〖 ∅ ;〗 √b)]$

Comment: To AJH: very interesting comment.  Please edit your posting to include all of the work from your last comment.  Also, you might explain, directly in your posting, how you got the (*unusual*) idea that $~\displaystyle 1 + \left[\frac{x}{h}\right]^2 = \sin^2(\theta).~$  This seems like a very creative approach, given that the problem seems to be a problem in Real Analysis, rather than Complex Analysis, and $\sin^2(\theta) > 1$ is **off-limits** in Real Analysis.